# Telegram Bot send Message to bot

Tags: java, communication, telegram-bot

I have programmed a telegram bot. This works fine when sending to groups or to users. However I do a special requirement. I need to be able to send to another bot. When adding both bots to a group as administrators. I still cannot receive the message with my second bot. I only see it with my real user account, that is added to this group. 
What am I missing?
I used OKHttp to send the message

```
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.telegram.org/bot"+telSetup.getToken()+"/sendMessage?chat_id="+lAdr+"&parse_mode=HTML&text="+strMessage)
                .build();
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new MyIPProcessing(request.toString()));
```

and

```
        if (response.message().equals("OK")){
            List <String> lStr=response.request().url().encodedPathSegments();
```

...

to receive messages ... which basically works for communication with "real users".

Any ideas welcome ....

Answer (score 14):

According to [Bots FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots)

> Bots talking to each other could potentially get stuck in unwelcome loops.
>   To avoid this, we decided that bots will not be able to see messages from other bots regardless of mode.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to send a message to another bot directly?

Answer (score 6):

You can connect 2 (or more) bots with a private channel!

Just prompt the bots as admin in the channel.

Then when a bot send a post to the channel, other admin bots can see the message/file/...

Comment: OP wrote: `When adding both bots to a group as administrators. I still cannot receive the message with my second bot`

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko i say "channel" not "group"

Answer (score 0):

Bot wouldn't be able to send message to other bots. in most platform APIs it return an error. kindly go through the documentation for the client(bot) and see its functionalities