# My Telegram Bot can't read message sended by another Telegram Bot

Tags: java, botframework, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I have two Telegram bots, written in Java.
First bot send some message every 10 min. (It works).
Second bot must read this sended message, and store it to txt file...
 
But problem is that the second bot don't see this message... 
He see messages only from USERS.
M - bot
YR - user
[Chat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Ewd.png)
[Console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l73f3.png)

---

[Here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658536/telegram-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0) says if

> BotFather=>Bot=>Settings=>Group Privacy => Privacy mode disabled and >BotFather=>Bot=>Settings=>Allow Groups? => Groups are currently enabled

bots must see messages sent from one to another.
 
I did it, also bots was invited to new group with Administrator rights.
 Here code example (second bot):

```
public class TelegramBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

public final String BOT_TOKEN = "****************************";
public final String BOT_NAME = "*****************";

@Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    long inChatID = 0;
    int inMessID = 0;
    String inText = "";
    try {  // from chanel
        inChatID = update.getChannelPost().getChatId();
        inText = update.getChannelPost().getText();
        inMessID = update.getChannelPost().getMessageId();
    } catch (Throwable t1) {};
    try {  // from chat
        inChatID = update.getMessage().getChatId();
        inText = update.getMessage().getText();
        inMessID = update.getMessage().getMessageId();
    } catch (Throwable t2) {};

    System.out.println(inChatID);
    System.out.println(inMessID);
    System.out.println(inText);
}

@Override
public String getBotUsername() {
    return BOT_NAME;
}

@Override
public String getBotToken() {
    return BOT_TOKEN;
}
}
```

If I send any message like user, i getting in console ChatID, MessID, Text...

But if first bot send some message, i got nothing. Help me with this issue. 
Any suggestion where my mistake ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Telegram Bot send Message to bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617889/telegram-bot-send-message-to-bot)

Comment: Yes, but my problem that I need that my bot reads the messages sended by another bot. 
I don't need send message from one bot to another bot.

Comment: That is the exact feature that is disabled, bots cannot see each other's messages within a given channel as this can cause "bot storms" where bots get into an infinite loop of replying to each other without any human interaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding this two bots to channel with administrator rights. 
It's don't works with GROUP CHAT. 
Now i can see message sended from another bots.
But there is another problem: all messages sended by any bot in channel throws like channel message, with out Bot ID, Bot Name, etc... 
So, I just can read message text, and parse it.