# Telegram: Send message to bot from different script

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot that handles user input to perform actions on links that are sent.

In my Telegram Bot I have:

```
def handle_message(bot, update):
    url = update.message.text
    # do parsing and add url to database

dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters=Filters.text, callback=handle_message))
```

However I want to also be able to send a URL to the bot from a POST request. i.e. use the telegram bot's API to send a message to itself so it can parse the link.

How can I send a POST request to my telegram bot and have it run `handle_message()` on the input?

Answer (score 1):

It is technically [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47617961/12137863) for bots to communicate with each other (and therefore with themselves).

Comment: Bots can see other bots' messages in channels.